# SVG file is not displayed in android flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, svg, widget

This is my pubspec.yaml file code:

```
    flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/logo.png
    - assets/welcome_bg.jpg
    - assets/logo-nbg.png
    - assets/create_screen_icon.svg
    - assets/upload_image.svg
```

and this is my container inside a column widget carrying the SVG File

```
Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/upload_image.svg',
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,)
                  ),
```

I have tried all the options suggested like cleaning the project. Running flutter again and getting dependencies again. Even after it is displaying an empty container. Any solution to this ?

Comment: are there any errors shown?

Comment: FYI. There is an issue opened. https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/1016

Answer (score 0):

Please set proper assets alignment.

If you need any reference, you can use this git hub repository and check yaml file.

Git link: https://github.com/JayswalViraj/Technource-Practical/blob/master/pubspec.yaml